# CSS word wrap second line of text

Tags: html, css

How can I make the text stay "on it's own side" when it's overflowing the first row?

I have a section that holds two divs.
The two divs are positioned side by side but if the first row is full it starts on a new line below the first div. (and that is the problem)

The first div is 120px wide because that is the widest text that can be printed there.
The second div is/should be the rest of the screen.

I created a link to jafiddle also in case the one on the page does not make it clear.
The problem occures when you have a smal window (phones etc.).

The page is generated from php.

http://jsfiddle.net/tL2fkLhq

```css
.section{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
    }
    .pTrans1{
        float: left;
        width: 120px;
        color: red;

    }
    .pTrans2{
        display: inline;
        
    }
```

```html
<section><div class='pTrans1'>15<font color='blue'>1120Z</font></div> <div class='pTrans2'><b>Meterologisk observation från den 15e kl 12:20 svensk tid.<font color=green> (32 minuter sedan)</font></b></div></section><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `display: table-cell;` in `.pTrans2` instead of `display: inline;`.

```
.pTrans2{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tL2fkLhq/6/)**

```css
.section{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.pTrans1{
   float: left;
   width: 120px;
   color: red;

}
.pTrans2{
    display: table-cell;
      
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class='pTrans1'>15<font color='blue'>1120Z</font></div>
    <div class='pTrans2'><b>Meterologisk observation från den 15e kl 12:20 svensk tid.<font color=green> (32 minuter sedan)</font></b></div>
</section><br>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `display: table;`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tL2fkLhq/3/)**

```css
.section{
   display: table;
}
.pTrans1{
   width: 120px;
   color: red;
   display: table-cell;
 }
.pTrans2 {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<section>

    <div class='pTrans1'>15<font color='blue'>1120Z</font></div>
    <div class='pTrans2'><b>Meterologisk observation från den 15e kl 12:20 svensk tid.<font color=green> (32 minuter sedan)</font></b></div>

</section><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have already done a similar example, which I would like to share. You need to use positioning for this case. This is a case of fixed-fluid:

```
+-------+-----------+
| FIXED | FLUUUUUID |
+-------+-----------+
```

Or

```
+-------+-----------+
| FIXED | FLUUUUUID |
|       | FLUUUUUID |
+-------+-----------+
```

Fixed-Fluid Model. In my snippet, I have demonstrated two kinds of examples. In the first case, the fluid is less in size. And the next has too long content.

**Snippet**

```css
.parent {position: relative; margin: 0 0 15px; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px; padding-left: 100px;}
.parent .fixed {position: absolute; left: 5px; width: 90px; background-color: #99f;}
.parent .fluid {background-color: #f99;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="fixed">Fixed</div>
  <div class="fluid">Fluid</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="fixed">Fixed</div>
  <div class="fluid">Fluid Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque animi placeat, expedita tempora explicabo facilis nulla fuga recusandae officia, maiores porro eaque, dolore et modi in sapiente accusamus id aut.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `position: absolute` is a little bit exaggerated here, I think.

Comment: @KittMedia The situation compels it. :) Fixed-Fluid. Or you need to use the table hack, as this is better than that.

Comment: No, as you can see at least 2 answers with just 2 small changes in the given code. :)

Comment: @KittMedia Yup. I can see that. :) When I started web dev, even I was using that code, and later found out, table is not good for layouts. Let it be `<table>` or `display: table`, that doesn't matter. No tables for layout.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.pTrans2` as block element with a `margin-left`:

```
.section{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.pTrans1{
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    color: red;

}
.pTrans2 {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 120px; 
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9a6zu13c/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
.section {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.pTrans1 {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  color: red;
}

.pTrans2 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 120px;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/tL2fkLhq/5/)**

Comment: @Andreas , experience my dear friend ;)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using the new flex-box spec over display: table. This is strictly personal, but I have a deep hatred for the CSS table system which always seems to act in a way that I don't want it to.

So, to copy Nenad Vracars answer with a slight modification:

You can use `display: flex;`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tL2fkLhq/9/)**

```css
section{
   display: flex;
}
.pTrans1{
   width: 120px;
   color: red;
 }
.pTrans2 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>

    <div class='pTrans1'>15<font color='blue'>1120Z</font></div>
    <div class='pTrans2'><b>Meterologisk observation från den 15e kl 12:20 svensk tid.<font color=green> (32 minuter sedan)</font></b></div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change second div like this

```
.pTrans2{
        width: calc(100% - 120px);
        margin-left: 120px;
}
```